# How to overcome returning ID from a database insert method design challenge

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

It will probably be a long post but please bear with me. The basic idea is this:

```
public int InsertPersonAndGetPersonId(Person person){
    _dbContext.Insert(person);
    return person.PersonId;
}
```

The method above is simple but it violates clean programming principles.

1. It is against Command/Query separation in methods.
2. It does more than one job.

When I am evaluating different approaches, I usually list the pros and cons and choose the one that has the least cons and the least trade-offs. Therefore, honestly, the method above looks better than the alternatives listed below. But I still would like to get the opinions of SO community and perhaps I learn a new pattern that works best with this challenge.

### Alternative #1

The one alternative is to have two methods. While the one is inserting new records, the other gets the lastly added `personId` from database. But this is not reliable unless you prevent database from accepting new person insertion between the time you insert a record and get its id from database.

You can even do filtering by the a property of `Person` (`Name` for instance) when getting the record from database but in addition to what I said above, there can also be more than one person who have the same name but different `PersonId`s.

It is also doing one more database trip. I am a pragmatic person and don't like to speculate about performance without actually measuring it. However, if I can prevent something with a simple change which will contribute to the performance even slightly, then I find it silly not to do it. Of course, while doing it, I also consider clean code practices.

### Alternative #2

The other method can be to change `InsertPersonAndGetPersonId` is in and have something like following:

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    private int _personId;

    public void InsertPerson(Person person){
        _dbContext.Insert(person);
        _personId = person.PersonId;
    }

    public int GetLastPersonId
        return _personId;
    }
}
```

Even though I don't like the name of this method `GetLastPersonId()`, which may bring a different `personId` than expected but let's assume that it returns the `id` of `person` object. The reason it is bad, besides what I already said, it is modifying the state of the object, therefore have a side effect.

### Alternative #3

We can simply have the method below:

```
public void InsertPerson(Person person){
    _dbContext.Insert(person);
    _personId = person.PersonId;
}
```

and since `person` is reference type, we can access `person.PersonId` like following:

```
var personRepository = new PersonRepository();
var person = new Person() {Name="Hello"};
personRepository.InsertPerson(person);
Console.WriteLine(person.PersonId);
```

Did I like it? No! It is way too hidden and unpredictable and you don't really know it unless you check the implementation detail and then we break the beauty of abstraction.

### Alternative #4

We can use `out` like follows:

```
public void InsertPerson(Person person, out int personId){
    _dbContext.Insert(person);
    personId = person.PersonId;
}
```

But this looks more silly and cumbersome than the first one `InsertPersonAndGetPersonId`. If I am going to have to return something, then I would return it using `return` and make the signature more explicit for the developers. Also in fact, `out` and `ref` makes more sense when we need to return multiple values. For instance `TryParse()`, returns `boolean` but also you can get the parsed value using `out` or `ref` too.

## Update

Due to a couple of comments, I decided to clarify my question a little bit more. What I am asking is how to get the `PersonId` without breaking the clean code principles. I am using EF and therefore getting the id from database is not a problem and in fact you can see it in my first example. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Returning the id is not a problem, returning it without breaking the clean coding principles, that is the problem. Also I am using Entity Framework so it is not an issue.

Comment: Can you use a `Guid` instead of `int`?

Comment: See [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/11/cqs-versus-server-generated-ids/), it might be helpful.

Comment: You have already implemented the cleanest and simplest approach.  You are creating a database entry, not querying the database.  All the other approaches add needless complication in an effort to achieve a separation that serves no more than an aesthetic purpose.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, Yacoub, your comments are confusing and irrelevant. The question is about design, not implementation. That means though that it may be a better fit at http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CodeCaster, if OP can use a `Guid` instead of `int`, this will enable him to generate the primary key of the entity in his application instead of at the database site. This means that OP can create a new `Guid` and assign it to `person.PersonId` at the consuming code and make his method return void. Please see the article I referenced.

Comment: @Yacoub I know of that article. You don't want to use guid _instead of_ int, as RDBMSes usually don't like guids as primary keys. That is also mentioned in the article. Proposed suggestion: use db-generated ID _and_ a GUID, making the pattern 1) Client generates GUID, 2) Client calls Create, 3) Client calls FindByGUID to find the newly created entity.  In my opinion, you also most certainly don't want to add a GUID property and column just for "clean design". Then you're choosing design over function.

Comment: CQS principles are guidelines, but there's always exceptions. For instance, would you eradicate methods such as `stack.pop`? There are cases where it's perfectly valid to return results directly from commands. Pushing CQS to the extreme will yield no benefits and will introduce accidental complexity. If you need infinite scalability then I would rely on domain events or returning a [Future/Promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) since that's the only contract which would allow you to seamlessly trade synchronous for asynchronous processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered raising an event? `PersonCreatedEvent` See also: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/11/cqs-versus-server-generated-ids/

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you have problem in design. The fact that you return this PersonId means that you need it to identify the person in your domain logic (business logic if you will).

The question is: **what database id has to do with person identity? Does it has any meaning in your domain?**
If it doesn't then use some other means to identify Person in your domain logic. This would give you at least following benefits:

1. You will be able to create person with Factory, (if it is an entity and probably aggregate root), giving him meaningful to your domain logic identity.
2. You will be able to save newly created person with Repository and will not have to deal with it's database id in you domain logic.

Then you'll be able to write something like this:

```
var newPerson = PersonFactory.Create();
//do some work with person in domain logic  
PersonRepository.Persist(newPerson);
```

Comment: It is actually DAL (Data Access Layer) where I want to know the `PersonId`. The reason is simple. When a person has been added, I want to use its `PersonId` to add some associated data in other tables, meaning `PersonId` is a foreign key in some other tables. However, when thinking of it again, I think this relationship should be done by EF instead so I should not ever have a need to get the `PersonId` out.